# Spring Mvc Wrong Date Format

Tags: spring, date, model-view-controller

I try to Spring mvc date formater with binder like this

```
@InitBinder
public void binder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateFormat.setLenient(true);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat,   true));
}
```

But I need format `"dd-MM-YYYY"`. If I use this format mysql save wrong date

Form Data: `07-12-1980`
MySql Data: `0013-05-02`

Answer (score 0):

In your POJO try adding this onto your date object.

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date dob;
```

Source: [here](https://gerrytan.wordpress.com/2013/05/21/binding-date-form-input-on-spring-mvc/)